# How can I link around a # href that jquery-ui-tabs relies on

Tags: jquery, href, jquery-ui-tabs

I re-purposed a jQuery based image slider from this tutorial here:

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui

For the most part it works great, except that the description side of things relies on the `href` being set to `"#fragment-whatever number"`. The basic HTML setup looks something like this:

```
<div id="featured" >  
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">  
        <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1">
          <a href="#fragment-1"><img src="images/image1-small.jpg" alt="" />
            <span>15+ Excellent High Speed Photographs</span>
          </a>
        </li>
</ul>

<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="">  
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery that runs it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sliderContainer > ul").tabs({
        fx: {
            opacity: "toggle"
        }
    }).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    $("#sliderContainer > ul").hover(function () {
        $("#sliderContainer > ul").tabs({
            event: "mouseover"
        }).tabs("rotate", 0, true);
    }, function () {
        $("#sliderContainer > ul").tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
```

Now, my problem with this is that I'd like to set the stuff in the list to a link other than a "#fragment". I have no idea how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have answered my own problem. 
I added an onclick event to the a tag after the dummy tag like so:

```
<a href="#fragment-1" onclick="javascript: goto_this_page('http://wherever.com')">
```

And I created this function somewhere above it to handle the onclick call:

```
var goto_this_page = function (this_href) {
var href = this_href;
window.location.href = href;
}
```

This seems to have solved the problem for the moment. Of course I'm open to a better solution.